# Co-support of an ideal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been unable to find a definition for the co-support of an ideal sheaf.
Given any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on some scheme $X$, its support is the set of points $x\in X$ such that $\mathcal{F}_x\neq0$. What is the co-support of an ideal sheaf then and how does it relate to its zero locus? Sorry of this is too simple.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal{I}\subset \mathcal{O}_X$ is an ideal sheaf on $X$, its co-support is the support of the quotient $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$